# Modelling and Querying a Product, Attribute, Property Relation with grouped Attributes

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to model a relation for Products, ProductsAttributes and ProductProperties for a shop system. But have the feeling that I am not on the right track to model or query the Attributes grouped with its Properties.

I have the following relations

**First: Attributes => Properties**

You should be able to create many different Attributes with ALL possible Properties for this Attribute in the Backend. So this is not Product specific and I did the following which works.

```
public class StockAttribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StockProperty> StockProperties { get; set; }
}

public class StockProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceDiff { get; set; }

    public int StockAttributeId { get; set; }
}
```

**Second: Product => specific selection of Attributes with a selection of available Properties for a Product**

To create a concrete product, I need 0-n Attributes with 1-n Properties. So I created the following table:

```
public class ProductAttributeProperty
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int StockAttributeId { get; set; }
    public StockAttribute StockAttribute { get; set; }

    public int StockPropertyId { get; set; }
    public StockProperty StockProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Example table:

```
ProductId | StockAttributeId | StockPropertyId
1 | 6 (color) | 12 (green)
1 | 6 (color) | 14 (blue)
1 | 7 (size)  | 16 (M)
1 | 7 (size)  | 17 (L)
```

This works but I got a problem now, when querying the product.

What I want to achieve is to query the Product with grouped Attributes, so that I can run through all Attributes and Properties with two foreach-loops to display SELECT Lists with the specific items.

```
Product (1)
|
+ Attribute_1 (color)
    +---------- Property_1 (green)
    +---------- Property_2 (blue)
+ Attribute_2 (size)
    +---------- Property_1 (M)
    +---------- Property_2 (L)
```

With the following query I get the correct Attributes but only as they are from with the ProductAttributeProperty-table row by row. My tries to add a GroupBy (Attributes) failed so far.

```
var product = await _context.Shop_Products
    .Include(x => x.Attributes)
        .ThenInclude(sa => sa.StockAttribute)
    .Include(x => x.Attributes)
        .ThenInclude(sp => sp.StockProperty) 
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: `ProductAttributeProperty` should have a collection `StockProperties`, i.e. the values (plural) of attribute X for Product Y. `StockAttribute.StockProperties` is the _domain_ (i.e. the list of possible values) of `StockAttribute`. For semantic reasons I would rename `StockProperty` to `StockValue`.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I mixed up the two different views on this problem. I have an admin view to the Attributes and the Properties (Values) with all possible expressions and I have a Product view with a specific combination of Attributes and Values, related to that product.

I solved it in this way:

1. StockAttributes and StockValues (Admin view)
2. ProductAttributes with an Attribute related to a product and with a collection of ProductAttributeValues.